# Creating Dictionary(key-value pairs) in Titanium+iPhone

Tags: iphone, titanium-mobile

Can any one tell me how to create a NSDictionary kind of object in Titanium. Have searched a lot but couldn't find any correct solution for creating key-value pairs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Titanium is written in Javascript, you can pass around JSON objects which can have key value pairs...

```
var dictionary = {
    key: 'value',
    key2: 'value2'
};
```

If you want to specifically make use of NSDictionary, then you'd have to go down the path of an iOS module.